# What variables are free in this formula?.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

So im new to logic and i get really confused on quantifier scope and bound namely what variables occur free in a formula im currently stuck on this one.

$$\exists X. (\forall Y. F(X,Y)) \implies G(X, Y, Z)$$

I don't understand what the free variables are in this formula im certain that $Z$ is free but for the $ X $  and $Y$ in $$G(X, Y, Z)$$ im not sure if they are free or bound as they seem to occur outside of the existential quantifiers scope.

Some help would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Set Braces to denote the order of evaluation. (Is the implication evaluated before the $\exist X$ or not?) Then, the scope should be clear.

Comment: The dot is a weird way to replace parentheses. I think that it means that the scope of the existential quantifier is the full formula.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: the dot as it was used by Russell and Whitehead is indeed rather weird these days. Requiring a dot or a bullet before the matrix of a quantified formula is very common nowadays in the logical syntax implemented in  [interactive theorem provers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant) and in [formal specification languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_language). It has the advantage of making it clear that the (IMHO weird and unhelpful) convention that quantifiers bind tighter than propositional connectives is not in force.

Comment: What text are you using? There are various conventions for omitting parentheses in logical formulas. Your use of a dot before the matrix of a quantified formula is unusual in some of the logical literature, but very common in the computer science literature. It would help us to help you if gave us a reference.